# Windows Phone 8.1 app with 2 hub sections

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

I've created a WP8.1 hub app with two hub sections. This produces in an odd behavior sliding between the two hubs. They don't "fly" into place like they are supposed to, it's more like a vertical scrollable view. If I then include a third hub section everything works just fine.

I've uploaded a YouTube video about it here: http://youtu.be/ns6bXmgajlQ

Is this a bug?

Is there a workaround (except the adding a third dummy section)?

Comment: It does seem like buggy behaviour to me as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Hub control does not go around and around as the Panorama does if there are only two HubSections.

This means that it is a feature, not a bug.

Quoted from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/08/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-what-controls-are-new.aspx

Comment: That's just one of the problems with it. It also acts up when swapping between the two sections, not snapping to the sections.

Comment: That is normal behaviour of the Hub Control when it just has two HubSections. You can't be expecting the Hub Control to behave exactly like the Panorama.