# panorama controls windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I 'm developping a windows phone 8.1 application and I would like to make a view with the panorama control but Its impossible to find the control

I have the Pivot control but not the panorama, is the panorama control is available on windows phone 8.1 ?

I have find nothing on it on the Internet so far :/

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Panorama** control has been renamed **Hub** because it’s now available on both *Windows Phone* and on *Windows*. So, you would do something like:

```
<Hub Header="My header">
<HubSection Header="My sub header">
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid />
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
<HubSection Header="My sub header 2">
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid />
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

There are some changes in the API, as you will use **HubSection** instead of a **PanoramaItem**, and you must have a **DataTemplate** inside a **HubSection,** so be sure to check the following reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub.aspx

There are some nuances as a slightly different and odd behaviour when you have only 2 HubSections, as noted here: [Windows Phone 8.1 app with 2 hub sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076048/windows-phone-8-1-app-with-2-hub-sections), but that may or may not be an issue for you. Some guidelines and implementation examples can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn449149.aspx

Comment: Thanks you very much dude  : )